# Воспроизведение видео из stream c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, видео, vlc

Необходимо считывать видео из БД и постепенно заполнять memory stream из которого будет оно читаться и воспроизводиться. Считывание с БД реализовано. Воспроизведение я попробовал через vlclib, но у меня ничего не получилось. Подскажите какое нибудь решение с помощью vlc или если есть другие библиотеки которые справятся с этой задачей напишите их пожалуйста.